# Anyone else having trouble adding solid background colors to Excel using Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi

I cannot get solid background colors to work in Apache POI when creating an Excel spreadsheet. Here's the code.

```
    XSSFFont calibri_8 = workbook.createFont();
    calibri_8.setFontHeight(8);
    calibri_8.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    calibri_8.setBold(true);

    XSSFCellStyle normalCenteredBeige_8_Wrapped = workbook.createCellStyle();
    normalCenteredBeige_8_Wrapped.setWrapText(true);
    normalCenteredBeige_8_Wrapped.setVerticalAlignment(
            VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    normalCenteredBeige_8_Wrapped.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    normalCenteredBeige_8_Wrapped.setFont(calibri_8);
    normalCenteredBeige_8_Wrapped.setFillBackgroundColor(new XSSFColor(
            new Color(255, 235, 155), new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
    normalCenteredBeige_8_Wrapped.setFillPattern(
            FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

I run the code and the output looks like this.

[image]

The cells that should have a light yellowish background are solid black. After searching through the available docs no one else seems to be having this issue. I'm pretty sure I'm following the [guide](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) correctly for the background colors. Any insight is greatly appreciated. I'm using POI 4.1.1.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154558/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-cell-using-apache-pio-4-1-0/58154633#58154633. Do using `normalCenteredBeige_8_Wrapped.setFillForegroundColor(...` instead of `normalCenteredBeige_8_Wrapped.setFillBackgroundColor(...`. `Excel` cell fills are pattern fills. Solid fill colors are solid pattern fills. The fill background color is the color behind the pattern.The fill foreground color is the color of the pattern.

Comment: @AxelRichter that worked like a charm! I completely missed the setFillForegroundColor setting. My bad. Was focused on the Background portion. Thank you for the help.